# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onlineMenu/wsgi'

Tags: django, heroku

I was going to host it using Heroku. But it does not work because of the problem with the profile.

This my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn onlineMenu.wsgi --log-file -
```

my wsgi.py code

```
    """
WSGI config for onlineMenu project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'onlineMenu.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

this is my Heroku log (not all)

> 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861587+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent
> call last): 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861588+00:00 app[web.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py",
> line 583, in spawn_worker 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861588+00:00 app[web.1]:
> worker.init_process() 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861589+00:00 app[web.1]:
> File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 119, in init_process 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861589+00:00 app[web.1]:
> self.load_wsgi() 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861589+00:00 app[web.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py",
> line 144, in load_wsgi 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861590+00:00 app[web.1]:
> self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi() 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861590+00:00
> app[web.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
> line 67, in wsgi 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861590+00:00 app[web.1]:
> self.callable = self.load() 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861591+00:00
> app[web.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 49, in load 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861591+00:00 app[web.1]: return
> self.load_wsgiapp() 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861591+00:00 app[web.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py",
> line 39, in load_wsgiapp 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861592+00:00 app[web.1]:
> return util.import_app(self.app_uri) 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861592+00:00
> app[web.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py",
> line 358, in import_app 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861592+00:00 app[web.1]:
> mod = importlib.import_module(module) 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861593+00:00
> app[web.1]: File
> "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/**init**.py", line 127,
> in import_module 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861593+00:00 app[web.1]: return
> _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861593+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import
> 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861594+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 991, in _find_and_load
> 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861594+00:00 app[web.1]: File "", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861594+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No
> module named 'onlineMenu/wsgi' 2020-10-23T16:04:08.861841+00:00
> app[web.1]: [2020-10-23 16:04:08 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting
> (pid: 10) 2020-10-23T16:04:09.011977+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-23
> 16:04:09 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
> 2020-10-23T16:04:09.012166+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-10-23 16:04:09
> +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Comment: Have you added gunicorn to your requirements.txt?

Comment: Yes, part of my requirements.txt file;
```... gunicorn==20.0.4 ....``